# Vue JS Tags Won't Render to HTML From JSON

Tags: javascript, vue.js, href, vue-router

I have JSON that contains HTML tags such as `href`, how can I click it without refreshing the page? I have already searched for it but no one is working...

#### Table

[image]

#### JSON

[image]
I'm using JSON datatable.

Comment: Can you update the question with proper example and your work?

Comment: did you used @click.prevent already ?

Comment: any vue js tags and script like @click is not working inside json, see the picture..

Comment: <router-link> tags should render into href, but because it's from json it won't render..

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're on [full build](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Terms), you cannot unfortunately add components dynamically like that. Have a read on [Template Compilation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Template-Compilation) and how to [make use of it](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile).

But in most cases (unless you're server-side rendering), you'd want to pass the router-link attributes as an object, something like:

```
const jsonData = [
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'First Vue JS',
    body: 'Vue JS',
    aksi: {
      text: 'Edit',
      attrs: {
        to: {
          name: 'edit',
          params: {
            // Assuming you have the `post` item here (usually while doing `v-for`)
            id: post.id
          }
        },
        class: 'btn btn-primary'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And rendering them, like:

```html
<table>
  <tr v-for="item in jsonData" :key="item.id">
    <td>{{item.title}}</td>
    <td>{{item.body}}</td>
    <td>
      <router-link v-bind="item.attrs">{{item.aksi.text}}</router-link>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you're not looping over them in the template, you might want to figure out how to do [column rendering](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) and customize this particular cell therein.

Comment: btw how about react js or angular ? which one is more flexible with laravel and json data ??

Comment: Well, this question is irrelevant, but I can say it's not a matter of which framework, but rather how you do it, because these frameworks are built on top of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

to me it seems you need to use auth guards

see here 
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards

1st thing you must try is whether your are able to log something when your route is clicked by using code here

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log(to);
  console.log(from);
})
```

if that's successful for this particular route try following

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {  
  if (to === "edit") {    
    next(false)
  }
}
```